# How do I sum 2 specific column rows in a DataFrame if some of the values are NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to create a new column, `Inches_z`. If there are values in both `Inches_x` and `Inches_y`, I want to sum the values in those 2 specific columns and return it as the result for `Inches_z` in the same row. If one `NaN` value exists, I'd like to return the row value that's not the `NaN` value. If both values are `NaN`, I'd like the resulting value to also be `NaN`. How do I do this?

I have:

```
Name    | Inches_x | Feet | Inches_y
------------------------------------
'Silvers'|    7    |   1   |     2
'Jones'  |    7    |   2   |     7
'Jackson'|    4    |  NaN  |    NaN
'Merole' |   NaN   |   2   |     8
'Kanoff' |   NaN   |   5   |    NaN
'Walker' |   NaN   |   8   |     0
'Smith'  |    8    |   0   |     3
```

I want:

```
Name    | Inches_x | Feet | Inches_y | Inches_z
-----------------------------------------------
'Silvers'|    7    |   1   |     2   |    9
'Jones'  |    7    |   2   |     7   |    14
'Jackson'|    4    |  NaN  |    NaN  |    4
'Merole' |   NaN   |   2   |     8   |    8
'Kanoff' |   NaN   |   5   |    NaN  |   NaN
'Walker' |   NaN   |   8   |     0   |    0
'Smith'  |    8    |   0   |     3   |    11
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 2):

Sum and fillna with the two columns

```
df['z'] = (df['Inches_x'] + df['Inches_y']).fillna(df['Inches_x']).fillna(df['Inches_y'])`
```

```
        Name  Inches_x  Feet  Inches_y     z
0  'Silvers'       7.0   1.0       2.0   9.0
1    'Jones'       7.0   2.0       7.0  14.0
2  'Jackson'       4.0   NaN       NaN   4.0
3   'Merole'       NaN   2.0       8.0   8.0
4   'Kanoff'       NaN   5.0       NaN   NaN
5   'Walker'       1.0   8.0       0.0   1.0
6    'Smith'       8.0   0.0       3.0  11.0
```

Comment: Thanks Kenan, this is exactly what I needed! How would I do something similar, but instead of summing, finding the max between the two columns?

Comment: Whats the logic? Fillna with min or max

Answer (score 2):

Use an explicit call to [`add()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html), in which case you can set a `fill_value` for when one of the values (but not both) is NaN:

```
df['Inches_z'] = df['Inches_x'].add(df['Inches_y'], fill_value=0.0)
```

Resulting DataFrame matches your stated expectation:

```
      Name  Inches_x  Feet  Inches_y  Inches_z
0  Silvers       7.0   1.0       2.0       9.0
1  Jones         7.0   2.0       7.0      14.0
2  Jackson       4.0   NaN       NaN       4.0
3  Merole        NaN   2.0       8.0       8.0
4  Kanoff        NaN   5.0       NaN       NaN
5  Walker        NaN   8.0       0.0       0.0
6  Smith         8.0   0.0       3.0      11.0
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I do something similar, but instead of summing, finding the max between the two columns?

Comment: @WillWild `df[['Inches_x', 'Inches_y']].max(axis=1)` works for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `sum` on `axis=1` with `min_count`:

```
df["Inches_z"] = df.filter(like="Inches_").sum(1, min_count=1)
print (df)

        Name  Inches_x  Feet  Inches_y  Inches_z
0  'Silvers'       7.0   1.0       2.0       9.0
1    'Jones'       7.0   2.0       7.0      14.0
2  'Jackson'       4.0   NaN       NaN       4.0
3   'Merole'       NaN   2.0       8.0       8.0
4   'Kanoff'       NaN   5.0       NaN       NaN
5   'Walker'       NaN   8.0       0.0       0.0
6    'Smith'       8.0   0.0       3.0      11.0
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I do something similar, but instead of summing, finding the max between the two columns?

Comment: Just call `max()` and `min()` instead of `sum`?